# How to disable logging for illegal host headers request in nginx

Tags: nginx, logging

In my nginx.conf, I add the following code to deny the illegal request:

```
server {
   ...
   ## Deny illegal Host headers
   if ($host !~* ^(www.mydomain.com|xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx)$) {
      return 444;
   }
   ...
}
```

But this request info always be written in access log, which is monitor request I think because they are so many and from two unsafe site and just HEAD request.

So how to stop logging these illegal request info to access log?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use separate server blocks

```
server {
    listen 80;

    # valid host names
    server_name www.example.com;
    server_name xx.xx.xx.xx;

    # you site goes here
}

# requests with all other hostnames will be caught by this server block
server {
    listen 80 default_server;
    access_log off;
    return 444;
}
```

That would be simple and efficient

Comment: I try your solution and I think it is simple and efficient for not using conditional statement and regex match. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

So shamed to find that nginx(1.7.0 and later) log moudle has provided [conditional logging](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_log_module.html#access_log), and the document example is just the status condition:

> The if parameter (1.7.0) enables conditional logging. A request will not be logged if the condition evaluates to “0” or an empty string. In the following example, the requests with response codes 2xx and 3xx will not be logged:
>
> ```
> map $status $loggable {
>     ~^[23]  0;
>     default 1;
> }
>
> access_log /path/to/access.log combined if=$loggable;
> ```

Also answer [Disable logging in nginx for specific request](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17423173/disable-logging-in-nginx-for-specific-request#answer-23942829) has mentioned this info. I just neglected it.

Now I add the following code to nginx log settings:

```
map $status $loggable {
    ~444 0;
    default 1;
}

access_log /var/log/nginx/access.log combined if=$loggable;
```

the illegal host headers request has not been logged.