# Logging requests with custom headers separately with nginx

Tags: nginx

As the title says, I would like to log certain requests which contain certain custom headers (e.g. `$http_x_custom_header_1` and `$http_x_custom_header_2`) separately. I've come across several similar examples (including [1](https://www.bjornjohansen.no/exclude-requests-from-nginx-access-log), [2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17423173/disable-logging-in-nginx-for-specific-request)) and the relevant documentation, but I must be missing something because I can't get it to work.

Here is what my `/etc/nginx/sites-enabled/example.com` conf file looks like:

```
map $http_x_custom_header_1 $X_CUSTOM_HEADER {
    1 1;
}

map $http_x_custom_header_2 $X_CUSTOM_HEADER {
    1 1;
}

server {

    listen 80;
    listen [::]:80;

    root /var/www/example.com/public_html;

    index index.html;

    server_name example.com;

    access_log /var/log/nginx/access.log combined if=!$X_CUSTOM_HEADER;
    access_log /var/log/nginx/custom-access.log combined if=$X_CUSTOM_HEADER;

    location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
    }

}
```

I've also tried commenting out the `access_log` line in `/etc/nginx/nginx.conf` out in case it was overriding the above configuration, but no luck.

edit: made some variables lowercase

Comment: I think the second `map` statement overwrites the first `map` statement as they are both controlling the same variable. Also, there is no support for a boolean *not* operator in the condition expression so, `!$X_CUSTOM_HEADER` always evaluates as *true*.

Comment: @RichardSmith It's OK if the second overrides the first, as I want the $X_CUSTOM_HEADER to get set if either of them matches. I did some testing using `$http_host` instead of the custom variables and there does seem to be support for the `!` in the conditional expression and the above code then functions as expected. It seems to be nginx is not recognizing my custom headers (i.e. `$http_x_custom_header_1`) is the problem!